# Interactive Rock Paper Scissors

Tags: python, beginner, rock-paper-scissors

I am a beginner in programming and this is the third program I've written.  This is an interactive game of rock, paper, scissors, capable of being modified to any number of turns.  I would love to see how a more experienced programmer could simplify this and make it smaller.  Please let me know how I could change this program to be easier to understand for other programmers or any general layout/design rules I should keep in mind when writing future programs.  I just have the *slightest* feeling that this code could be more compact.

```
args = ['rock', 'paper', 'scissors']
user_score = 0
comp_score = 0
turn = 3
print 'ROCK, PAPER, SCISSORS!'
print 'Best out of %d' % (turn)
while turn > 0:
    user = raw_input('Choose ' + ", ".join(args) + ' > ')
    comp = random.choice(args)
    proof = 'Computer: %s' % (comp)
    if user == 'q':
        break
    elif (user == args[0] and comp == args[2]) or (user == args[1]\
          and comp == args[0]) or (user == args[2] and comp == args[1]):
        print proof
        print 'Win \n'
        turn -= 1
        user_score += 1
    elif user == comp:
        print proof
        print 'Tie \n'
        turn -= 1
    elif user not in args:
        print 'INVALID INPUT \n'
    else:
        print proof
        print 'Lose \n'
        turn -= 1
        comp_score += 1 
print '\n User scored: %d \n Computer scored: %d \n' % (user_score,comp_score)
if user_score > comp_score:
    print 'Winner!'
elif user_score < comp_score:
    print 'Loser'
else:
    print 'Draw'
```

Comment: You should also have a look at [the style guide](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).

Answer (score 6):

This is pretty good, but there are a few things that needed to be improved. Here are a few of those things, specifically regarding your, odd, design.

- Using `%` for string formatting is deprecated. To format strings, you should use `str.format`. For example, you'd do this: `print 'Best out of {0}'.format(turn)`.
- Your naming is, strange. For example, I'd rename `args` to `possible_moves`. Good variable names should reflect the purpose of the variable.
- The way you've designed this is odd. I'd reccomend an [object-oriented-design.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming) with a `Game` class with certain methods and attributes to manage a game. A few things that I'd reccomend implementing would be:

  - A `total_turns` attribute which would allow there to be a custom amount of turns.
  - A `Game.pick_move` to choose a random choice.

That's about all I can think of for improvement. If there's anything that you want me to comment on, just tell me about it. I hope this helps!